# Pandas select rows where columns are dynamic and a single column's value is greater than zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume a DataFrame is created where the number of columns and column names is dynamic.
So you could have a DataFrame like:

```
two = pd.DataFrame({'one' : pd.Series([10, 0, 10], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
   'two' : pd.Series([0, 0, 10.], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])})

 one   two
a   10   0.0
b    0   0.0
c   10  10.0
```

Or you could have a Dataframe like:

```
three = pd.DataFrame({'blue' : pd.Series([10, 0, 10], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
   'red' : pd.Series([0, 0, 10], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
   'two' : pd.Series([0, 0, 10], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])})

   blue  red  two
a    10    0    0
b     0    0    0
c    10   10   10
```

So you won't know how many columns or the column names until run time. There is no limit on number of columns.

How do you select rows where only one column is greater than zero?

So for a given row if all column values are zero or if more than one column value is greater than zero its excluded from selection.

From the two above examples I'd respectfully output:

```
   one  two
a   10    0
```

and

```
   blue  red  two
a    10    0    0
```

Comment: test my code against your inputs and kindly let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the entire DataFrame for the condition and sum across rows. If that equals 1, the condition holds:

```
two.loc[(two>0).sum(axis=1)==1]
Out: 
   one  two
a   10  0.0


three.loc[(three>0).sum(axis=1)==1]
Out: 
   blue  red  two
a    10    0    0
```

Or with a lambda:

```
three.loc[lambda x: (x>0).sum(axis=1)==1]
Out: 
   blue  red  two
a    10    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

**two[two[two > 0].count(axis=1) > 0].head(1)**

Say you have

```
two = pd.DataFrame({'one' : pd.Series([10, 0, 10, 9], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), 'two' : pd.Series([0, 0, 10., 4.6], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), 'three' : pd.Series([5, -1, 7, -1], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])})
```

[image]
[image]

Select row where at least one column has value is greater than 0. 
`head(1)` will select the top row

[image]

Reference: [pandas: How do I select rows based on if X number of columns is greater than a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781253/pandas-how-do-i-select-rows-based-on-if-x-number-of-columns-is-greater-than-a-n)